# Как можно сделать new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType. Имя типа <T> имею в виде String.

Tags: servlet, gson

Всем привет! Использую Gson для конвертации HashMap map в JsonObject, далее JsonObject я отправляю на сервер где нужно его преобразовать обратно в HashMap. Собственно код ниже.

Код на клиенте:

```
public void sendDataToServer(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    }.getType();

    String data = new Gson().toJson(map, type);
    String mapType = type.toString();
    //mapType теперь = "java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>"

    JsonObject dataToServer = new JsonObject();
    dataToServer.addProperty("map", data);
    dataToServer.addProperty("mapType", mapType);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("dataToServer", dataToServer.toString())
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://some Url")
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Код на сервере:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        JSONObject dataFromClient = new JSONObject(req.getParameter("dataToServer"));

        String map = (String) dataFromClient.get("map");
        String mapType = (String) dataFromClient.get("mapType");
        //mapType = "java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>"
        //тут может быть любой тип

        //как вместо этого хардкода:
        Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        }.getType();

        //сделать Type type = new TypeToken<свой тип>(){}.getType();
        //ну или как-то выкрутиться из этой ситуации

        HashMap<String, String> result = new Gson().fromJson(map, type);
        //с хардкодом все работает хорошо.

        //... Дальше идет остальная логика...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<T>` не может работать по понятным причинам. Для того, чтобы можно было преобразовать JSON в нужный объект, достаточно в `fromJson` передать *любой* инстанс типа `Type`. Поскольку `Type` является интерфейсом, можно без проблем сделать свою реализацию этого типа, тем не менее нужно отметить, что простого `Type` -- недостаточно, поскольку нужно также учесть `GenericArrayType` и `ParameterizedType` (чтобы Gson умел воссоздавать массивы и параметрические типы соответственно). Наиболее простой способ, который приходит в голову -- сериализация. Благо, Gson-овские реализации типов являются `Serializable`. В итоге должно получиться что-то типа:

- Для сериализации: `Type -> [object output stream] -> byte[] -> [to Base64] -> String`;
- Для десериализации: `Type <- [object input stream] <- byte[] <- [from Base64] <- String`.

Я сторонник TDD только на половину -- пишу тесты после реализации кода, но здесь начну с теста:

```java
abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    protected abstract String toTypeString(Type type)
            throws IOException;

    protected abstract Type fromTypeString(String view)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final Type expectedType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        }.getType();
        final String typeString = toTypeString(expectedType);
        final Type actualType = fromTypeString(typeString);
        assertThat(actualType.toString(), is(expectedType.toString()));
        final Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson("{\"foo\":\"1\",\"bar\":\"20\",\"baz\":\"300\"}", actualType);
        assertThat(map, instanceOf(HashMap.class));
        assertThat(map.size(), is(3));
        assertThat(map.get("foo"), is("1"));
        assertThat(map.get("bar"), is("20"));
        assertThat(map.get("baz"), is("300"));
    }

}
```

И конкретная реализация теста:

```
public class SerializationIntegrationTest
        extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Override
    protected String toTypeString(final Type type)
            throws IOException {
        return serializableToBase64((Serializable) type);
    }

    @Override
    protected Type fromTypeString(final String typeString)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return (Type) base64ToSerializable(typeString);
    }

}
```

И, собственно, логика преобразования из любого `Serializable` в строку и обратно:

```
public final class Serialization {

    private static final BaseEncoding base64Encoding = base64();

    private Serialization() {
    }

    public static String serializableToBase64(final Serializable serializable)
            throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try ( final ObjectOutput objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream) ) {
            objectOutput.writeObject(serializable);
        }
        return base64Encoding.encode(outputStream.toByteArray());
    }

    public static Serializable base64ToSerializable(final CharSequence encoded)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64Encoding.decode(encoded));
        try ( final ObjectInput objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream) ) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Serializable object = (Serializable) objectInputStream.readObject();
            return object;
        }
    }

}
```

Код был реализован и тестировался с помощью:

- Gson 2.8.0
- Guava 20.0
- JUnit 4.12

К сожалению, результат преобразования в Base64 на моей машине составляет строку длиной в 428 base64-символов (или 321 октет). Такова цена прямого преобразования сериализируемого типа для передачи через текст-ориентированные сообщения с возможностью 100% восстановления. Поскольку с такой сериализацией объектов через `ObjectOutputStream` я не работал, не могу точно сказать, будет ли этот способ работать, если передать такое сообщение с одной платформы на другую (ввиду двоичной совместимости). Но должно 100% работать, если одна и та же версия Gson будет задействована и на клиенте, и на сервере. Если версии расходятся, корректное воссоздание объекта на сервере не гарантируется, хотя `serialVersionUID` для типов в Gson, по-видимому, всегда равен `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Если же гонять 400+ символов, которые кодируют состояние типа для Gson, не хочется, можно попробовать написать парсер, который будет преобразовывать результаты `Type.toString` в конкретные типы, предоставляемые самим Gson. Но это скорее куда более сложный путь, и он требует большей прокачки, потому как нужно ещё написать парсер. В следующем решении не гарантируется полный разбор всех возможных комбинаций, которые могут встречаться в `toString`. Кроме того, используется `com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types`, который со временем могут прикрыть.

Сначала тесты:

```
public class TypesIntegrationTest
        extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Override
    protected String toTypeString(final Type type)
            throws IOException {
        return type.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected Type fromTypeString(final String view)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return parseConcreteType(view);
    }

}
```

А также юнит-тест для парсера:

```
public final class TypesTest {

    @Test
    public void testJavaLangString() {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<String>() {
        }.getType();
        assertThat(parseConcreteType(type.toString()), is((Type) String.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJavaLangSerializable() {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<Serializable>() {
        }.getType();
        assertThat(parseConcreteType(type.toString()), is((Type) Serializable.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJavaLangStringSimple() {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<String>() {
        }.getType();
        assertThat(parseConcreteType("java.lang.String"), is(type));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJavaLangStringArray() {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<String[][][]>() {
        }.getType();
        assertThat(parseConcreteType(type.toString()), is(type));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJavaUtilHashMapJavaLangStringJavaLangString() {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {
        }.getType();
        assertThat(parseConcreteType(type.toString()), is(type));
    }

    @Test
    public void testJavaUtilHashMapJavaLangStringArrayJavaLangStringArrayArray() {
        final Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String[], String>[][]>() {
        }.getType();
        assertThat(parseConcreteType(type.toString()), is(type));
    }

}
```

Сам парсер написан с помощью [JParsec](https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec), который предоставляет удобные средства для разбора структурированного текста с возможностью преобразования символов в нужные объекты прямо на лету.

```
public final class Types {

    private Types() {
    }

    public static Type parseConcreteType(final CharSequence typeString) {
        return P.anyType.parse(typeString);
    }

    private static final class L {
        private static final Pattern space = isChar(' ');
        private static final Pattern dot = isChar('.');
        private static final Pattern comma = isChar(',');
        private static final Pattern closedBrackets = string("[]");
        private static final Pattern leftAngleBracket = isChar('<');
        private static final Pattern rightAngleBracket = isChar('>');
        private static final Pattern classKeyword = string("class");
        private static final Pattern interfaceKeyword = string("interface");
        private static final Pattern identifier = isChar(Character::isJavaIdentifierPart).many();
        private static final Pattern fullyQualifiedName = identifier.next(dot).many().optional().next(identifier);
    }

    private static final class LP {
        private static final Parser<Void> space = L.space.toScanner("<' '>");
        private static final Parser<Void> classKeyword = L.classKeyword.toScanner("<CLASS>");
        private static final Parser<Void> interfaceKeyword = L.interfaceKeyword.toScanner("<INTERFACE>");
        private static final Parser<Type> fullyQualifiedClass = L.fullyQualifiedName.toScanner("<FULLY QUALIFIED CLASS>").source().map(Types::getClass);
        private static final Parser<Integer> arity = L.closedBrackets.toScanner("<ARITY>").source().many().map(List<String>::size);
        private static final Parser<Void> leftAngleBracket = L.leftAngleBracket.toScanner("<'<'>");
        private static final Parser<Void> rightAngleBracket = L.rightAngleBracket.toScanner("<'>'>");
        private static final Parser<Void> delimiter = L.comma.next(L.space).toScanner("<', '>");
    }

    private static final class P {
        private static final Parser<Type> simpleType = LP.classKeyword.or(LP.interfaceKeyword).next(LP.space).next(LP.fullyQualifiedClass);
        private static final Reference<Type> forwardingComplexType = newReference();
        private static final Parser<Type[]> typeParameterization = array(LP.leftAngleBracket, forwardingComplexType.lazy().sepBy(LP.delimiter), LP.rightAngleBracket).map(a -> getTypeParameters((Collection<?>) a[1]));
        private static final Parser<Type> complexType = array(LP.fullyQualifiedClass, typeParameterization.optional(), LP.arity.optional()).map(a -> resolveComplexType((Type) a[0], (Type[]) a[1], (Integer) a[2]));
        private static final Parser<Type> anyType = simpleType.or(complexType);

        static {
            forwardingComplexType.set(complexType);
        }
    }

    private static Type[] getTypeParameters(final Collection<?> parameters) {
        return parameters.stream().toArray(Type[]::new);
    }

    private static Class<?> getClass(final String className)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            switch ( className ) {
            case "boolean":
                return boolean.class;
            case "byte":
                return byte.class;
            case "short":
                return short.class;
            case "int":
                return int.class;
            case "long":
                return long.class;
            case "float":
                return float.class;
            case "double":
                return double.class;
            case "char":
                return char.class;
            case "void":
                return void.class;
            default:
                return Class.forName(className);
            }
        } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ex);
        }
    }

    private static Type resolveComplexType(final Type type, final Type[] typeParameters, final Integer arity) {
        final boolean isGeneric = typeParameters != null && typeParameters.length > 0;
        final boolean isArray = arity != null && arity > 0;
        if ( isGeneric && isArray ) {
            return makeArray(arrayOf(newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(null, type, typeParameters)), arity);
        }
        if ( isGeneric ) {
            return newParameterizedTypeWithOwner(null, type, typeParameters);
        }
        if ( isArray ) {
            return makeArray(arrayOf(type), arity);
        }
        return type;
    }

    private static Type makeArray(final Type type, final int arity) {
        Type complexType = type;
        for ( int i = 1; i < arity; i++ ) {
            complexType = arrayOf(complexType);
        }
        return complexType;
    }

}
```

Одним из минусов парсера выше, кроме сложности, могу назвать то, что `ParameterizedType.getOwnerType` всегда возвращает `null` и, таким образом, не поддерживаются внутренние классы.